# How to subscribe to observable multiple times?

Tags: rxjs, angular8

I have a table that needs to be refreshed each time a user delete a row, or edit data with a designate function called reloadUsersData();
I've created a BehaviorSubject that gets the table's data from a service - once the table is loaded - but i'm not sure that my implementation of reloadUsersData is good since i repeat the same code and resubscribe to the same observable ....

```
    export class TableBasicExample implements OnDestroy, OnInit{
           dataSource$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
           private subs: Subscription[] = [];

           constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}
                                
    
     ngOnInit() {

    this.subs.push(
      this.apiService.getUsers().subscribe((res: any) => {
  
        this.dataSource$.next(res);

      }));
     }

     reloadUsersData(){
      // how can i subscribe to the same api more effectively ?
      this.subs.push(
      this.apiService.getUsers().subscribe((res: any) => {
  
        this.dataSource$.next(res);

      }));

     }

     ngOnDestroy(): void {
       this.subs.forEach((us) => us.unsubscribe());
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately, this can be simplified! I'm assuming that `.getUsers()` emits one array of users and completes. With that in mind, you have the right idea with creating a subject to handle reload events.

One strategy you can use in RxJS is to create an observable that includes a subject in its `.pipe()`. This is because a `Subject` inherits all capabilities of an `Observable`.

Here's the code.

```
export class TableBasicExample {
  private fetchEvent = new BehaviorSubject<'fetch'>('fetch');
  public users$: Observable<User[]>;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
    this.users$ = this.fetchEvent.pipe(
      switchMapTo(this.apiService.getUsers())
    );
  }

  reloadUsersData() {
    this.fetchEvent.next('fetch');
  }
}
```

We create a `BehaviorSubject` (which is an extension of `Subject`) to handle our fetch event. We have it emit the string `'fetch'`, but it could honestly be any value.

Next, we declare the main `Observable` we use for our table rendering. It will subscribe to `fetchEvent` and will `switchMap` to an inner observable (`.getUsers()`) and emit its value.

Last, we have our public method that will emit a new value in our private `BehaviorSubject`.

In your component's template file, you can subscribe to this observable using the `async` pipe.

```
<table *ngIf="users$ | async as users">
  <tr *ngFor="user of users">
    <!-- table row data -->
  </tr>
</table>
<button (click)="reloadUsersData()">Reload</button>
```

The `async` pipe handles the subscribe/unsubscribe events for you, so you no longer need `onInit` and `onDestroy` in your component's TS file.

And that's it! When `reloadUsersData()` is invoked, it causes `fetchEvent` to emit a new value. Because `users$` has an active subscription, it will receive that new value, and again subscribe to the inner `switchMap` observable.

**Note:** The `switchMapTo(obs$)` operator is similar to `switchMap((value)=>$obs)` operator. It's just a little less code because we don't actually need the value from our `BehaviorSubject`.